# Controlling the style of individual spry tabbed panels in Dreamweaver CS4

Tags: dreamweaver, panels, spry, tabbed

Hi I'm using Dreamweaver CS4's spry tabbed panels. I want to modify just one tab panel's style so that all the tab's backgrounds will look different. I've tried looking through the "SpryTabbedPanels.css" properties but no luck, just one that modifies ALL of them called ".TabbedPannelsTab"

Anyone familiar with this stuff give me some advice please, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This question is really about CSS. IN this particular case, you can add an ID to the tab you want to modify and then apply CSS to that id selector:

```
#myCustomTab{
    /* custom styles */
}
```

Just make sure that you override any style you don't want to be inherited from the main.